# How to make array name as variable in vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

i want to change lang on click href link

```
  var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        lang:'fr',
            ar:{
                title:'العربية',
                text:'نص',
            },
            en:{
                title:'English',
                text:"It is a long established fact ",
            }
      },
        methods:{
            changelang : function(){
                return lang;
            }
        }
    })

english flag

    {{en.title}}
    //to//
    {{lang.title}}
```

Comment: Use i18n instead

Answer (score 0):

1) That's not practical conversion using anchor href when things getting complicated. you might want to use `vue-router` to switch `view` between `/ar` or `/en` for different language views.

2) `lang:'fr'` you added french as default locale, yet not seen fr translation text added neither.

3) There's a il8n localization/translation plugin for vue here. Which is best for your case https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/